# Automate PyDev Interpreter setup

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jython, pydev

I have a scenario where I want to be able automate the setting up of various Python interpreters for use in PyDev.  These interpreters have special environment variables, forced built-ins and libraries defined.  Is there a way through perhaps an .ini file or through the PyDev / Jython API to programmatically define Python interpreters for PyDev?

Answer (score 1):

In the Java API it's something as:

```
IInterpreterManager manager = PydevPlugin.getPythonInterpreterManager(true);
manager.setInfos(exesList, interpreterNamesToRestore, monitor);
```

The exesList is a list of `org.python.pydev.ui.pythonpathconf.InterpreterInfo` and the `interpreterNamesToRestore` a list of the interpreters that were changed (i.e.: should have the pythonpath restored).

You could probably do this from Jython, but PyDev provides no hooks where you'd be able to do that (i.e.: it only provides hooks for setting up an editor), so, the best solution right now would be creating a simple eclipse plugin that had an earlyStartup to do the configuration you want (should be straightforward).

Comment: This solution worked fine for me. I think it's a much better approach than working with plugin customization files as discussed in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question a while back after getting frustrated with Eclipse plug-ins fighting each other and ruining otherwise 'pristine' setups so I dug around and found these nifty tidbits:

[Eclipse run-time options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) (cli options for running what would otherwise be captive-UI features.

[Running Eclipse's update manager from the CLI](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html)

So, if you read through the run-time options a bit, you'll come across..

```
eclipse.pluginCustomization {-pluginCustomization}
the file system location of a properties file containing default settings for 
plug-in preferences. These default settings override default settings 
specified in the primary feature. Relative paths are interpreted relative 
to the current working directory for Eclipse itself.
```

Which will probably do what you want.

Comment: I was also interested in configuring PyDev from the command-line when starting Eclipse. So I once configured PyDev manually (python interpreter, jython interpreter, initial interpreter commands, ...).  Then I used File/Export/General.../Preferences to save these settings, removed anything other than pydev settings from the file, and tried to use that file with the `-pluginCustomization` option. Problem is that only some settings are taken, like the initial interpreter commands for a PyDev console. But the Python and Jython interpreters are not used. Any idea?