# Automating Eclipse / Pydev setup

Tags: python, eclipse, fabric

I am working on a large Python project, using Launchpad and Eclipse as tools. We have many bugfix tickets. Each time I start a new ticket, there is a lengthy setup process, and I would like to script it, probably using a Fabric fabfile, but a shell solution will be fine also.

The codebase is made up of 6 trunks in launchpad, and these are set up as 6 projects in eclipse. Then a debug profile is set up for the server launcher, and is different with each branch. All 6 are required to run the application. A bugfix often requires a commit to only one of those branches.

This leads to a mess like this in th ePydev Package Explorer:

[image: Pydev Package Explorer]

The launcher has several parameters, for example:

[image: Pydev Debug Configuration - Main]

[image: Pydev Debug Configuration - Arguments]

A similar question but not with specific enough answers:
[Automate PyDev Interpreter setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675360/automate-pydev-interpreter-setup)

I will probably look at using Vagrant eventually, and move back to vi/tmux, but for now I will work with the standard developer setup of Eclipse and local files.

**Question(s)**

Is there a way to work with these in Eclipse as a single "project" ? Ideally a high-level folder which contains the 6 branches within it, and can be opened and closed.

How can this setup be scripted after the new branches are created on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With eclipse you can have projects require other projects.

Because python lacks a library form, or a "java package" or whatever the hell they are, I use a version control system to import packages from other projects.

I use SVN and subversive

When you define an exported property you can point it at the head rev of the other's trunk (or some branch... whatever) it's then as if the file is in 2 places but without copy and pasting or short-cuts, when you check out the repo it effectively is.

Related projects are difficult in Python as I said due to lack of "build". If project B requires project A and project B requires C also when I try to build (run => build remember) B A and C are built before B is rebuilt. (much like a makefile in a sense)

If your problem is "a huge list" remember you can have multiple workspaces. But a huge list isn't a problem, you can search just by typing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are using Bazaar, and I have no control over the structure of the SVN. I don't want to do anything that would affect other developers, just make my life easier.

Comment: @ardochhigh look up SVN exports, make sure you see what it does first, reply to this comment if you make an edit to your question and I'll try to help

Comment: OK Alec I will. Thanks for your advice, Sean.